# mysql query tracing

Tags: mysql

I see general_log=1 in the my.cnf but I am not able to find where exactly is mysql logging all the queries. I read that it usually logs into a file or table.

If it is a file then the file name is specified in my.cnf and I don't see that. If it is table which table does it log to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the general log will by in the MySQL data directory (/var/lib/mysql in most cases) and will be named host_name.log where host_name is your host name. You can change the log file location/name by add a log directive to my.cnf like this:

```
log=/var/lib/mysql/your_log_name
```

Note you must restart server or run `flush logs` in order for the change to take effect.

You can also restart mysqld using the `-l [file name]` option.